# Unable to implement Apple Pay in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, applepay

I'm trying to implement Apple Pay in my SwiftUI app and I'm stuck at showing the button.

I have done that by using `UIViewRepresentable`

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PassKit
import Foundation

struct ApplePayButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKPaymentButton, context: Context) {

    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKPaymentButton {
        let paymentButton = PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .plain, paymentButtonStyle: .black)
        return paymentButton
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate  {
        func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
            //
        }

        func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
            print("did authorize payment")

        }

        func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerWillAuthorizePayment(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
            print("Will authorize payment")
        }
    }
}



class ApplePayManager: NSObject {
    let currencyCode: String
    let countryCode: String
    let merchantID: String
    let paymentNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork]
    let items: [PKPaymentSummaryItem]

    init(items: [PKPaymentSummaryItem],
           currencyCode: String = "EUR",
           countryCode: String = "AT",
           merchantID: String = "c.c.c",
           paymentNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork] = [PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, PKPaymentNetwork.visa]) {
        self.items = items
        self.currencyCode = currencyCode
        self.countryCode = countryCode
        self.merchantID = merchantID
        self.paymentNetworks = paymentNetworks
    }

    func paymentViewController() -> PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController? {
        if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
            let request = PKPaymentRequest()
            request.currencyCode = self.currencyCode
            request.countryCode = self.countryCode
            request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
            request.merchantIdentifier = self.merchantID
            request.paymentSummaryItems = items
            request.merchantCapabilities = [.capabilityCredit, .capabilityDebit]
            return PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I do not want to use `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` because I want to use the native button.

When I click at the button I get this error:

`[General] Payment request is invalid: Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid in-app payment request" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid in-app payment request, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003aeebb0 {Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "PKPaymentRequest must contain an NSArray property 'paymentSummaryItems' of at least 1 valid objects of class PKPaymentSummaryItem" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=PKPaymentRequest must contain an NSArray property 'paymentSummaryItems' of at least 1 valid objects of class PKPaymentSummaryItem}}}`

View:

```
struct PaymentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var requestViewModel: RequestViewModel
    
    var applePayManager = ApplePayManager(items: [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Some Product", amount: 9.99)
    ])
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("By paying you agree to give the package to transporter.")
                // requestViewModel.respondToRequest(status: button.status)
                
                ApplePayButton()
                    .frame(width: 228, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        applePayManager.paymentViewController()
                    }
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Payment")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Done")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you passing the items?  The error message says you have no items

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the view code in the question. `var applePayManager = ApplePayManager(items: [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Some Product", amount: 9.99)
    ])` Do I need to set the delegate here? Because I tried but i could not

Comment: I am not a big fan of allocating objects, like your `ApplePayManager` in views, since views are ephemeral.  Pass an instance in from the environment.  Use the debugger to see if `items` really is empty.

Comment: I did this `request.paymentSummaryItems = [
                PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Some Product", amount: 9.99)
            ]` and now nothing happens. So the `paymentViewController` should open the payment sheet right? What about the delegate? Do i need to set it in the `makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKPaymentButton` I tried but I couldn't since there is no `PKPaymentButtonDelegate` @Paulw11

Comment: I also get this warning: `Result of call to 'paymentViewController()' is unused` here `.onTapGesture {
                        applePayManager.paymentViewController()
                    }`

Comment: That is correct, because you aren't doing anything with it. You need to actually present the view controller.

Comment: Check Apple-Pay-SwiftUI-2.0 repo by @nelglez on GitHub and build your service around it - that's one and only working solution for SwiftUI 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else is struggling like me: Here is the full code.

```
import Foundation
import PassKit

class PaymentHandler: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    func startPayment(paymentSummaryItems: [PKPaymentSummaryItem]) {
        
        // Create our payment request
        let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.de.xxx"
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "AT"
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "EUR"
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingContactFields = [.phoneNumber, .emailAddress]
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = [.masterCard, .visa]
        
        // Display our payment request
        let paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        paymentController.delegate = self
        paymentController.present(completion: { (presented: Bool) in })
    }
}


/**
 PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate conformance.
 */
extension PaymentHandler: PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

    func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
        completion(.success)
        print("paymentAuthorizationController completion(.success)")
    }

    func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
        print("DidFinish")
    }
    
    func paymentAuthorizationControllerWillAuthorizePayment(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
        print("WillAuthorizePayment")
    }

}

struct PaymentButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKPaymentButton, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKPaymentButton {
        return PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .plain, paymentButtonStyle: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Use it in the view:

```
PaymentButton()
    .frame(width: 228, height: 40, alignment: .center)
    .onTapGesture {
        paymentHandler.startPayment(paymentSummaryItems: paymentSummaryItems)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue where the country code was not clear there's a specific countryCode like for UK it should be GB and this isn't mentioned in the docs when getting this error there's a long list of country codes you might need to get your code from there according to your country